# Prove that the sequence $3+\frac{1}{n^2}$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

**Question:** Prove that the sequence defined by ${x_n}=3+\frac{1}{n^2}$ is Cauchy.

**My attempt:** Need to show that $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m,n>N \implies|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon.$

Fix $\epsilon>0$. (**Edit**: and let $m>n$.)

We have $|x_n-x_m|=|3+\frac{1}{n^2}-(3+\frac{1}{m^2})|$

$=|\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{m^2}|$

$=|\frac{m^2}{m^2n^2}-\frac{n^2}{m^2n^2}|$

$=|\frac{m^2-n^2}{m^2n^2}|$

$\le|\frac{m^2}{m^2n^2}|$

$=|\frac{1}{n^2}|=\frac{1}{n^2}.$

Then $\frac{1}{n^2}<\epsilon \implies n^2>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\implies n>\sqrt\frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

So choose $N=\lfloor\sqrt\frac{1}{\epsilon}\rfloor+1$ and the definition is satisfied. Q.E.D.

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: It's not entirely correct. You're changing $|m^2-n^2|$ with $|m^2|$, but what if $n$ is much larger than $m$?

Comment: In that case, could I just let $m>n$ at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, that would fix that problem.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add my thought to this as you did most of it. Often times, you replace the minus $-$ by the plus $+$. So this means:

$\left|\dfrac{m^2-n^2}{m^2n^2}\right| \le \dfrac{m^2+n^2}{m^2n^2}= \dfrac{1}{m^2}+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\le \dfrac{1}{m}+\dfrac{1}{n} < \dfrac{1}{N}+\dfrac{1}{N}=\dfrac{2}{N}< \epsilon$, if $N > \dfrac{2}{\epsilon}$. Thus you can say: choose $N > \dfrac{2}{\epsilon}$ and for $m, n > N$ then you have $|x_m-x_n| < \epsilon$, proving it a Cauchy Sequence.

Comment: If we're going into variations of the proof, I think it's even easier to note that $3<x_n,x_m<x_N$, so clearly $|x_n-x_m|<|x_N-3|$.